# How to post custom html tags with tinymce

Tags: html, tinymce

I am trying to insert some custom html with a custom button, which works fine like this:

```
editor.selection.setContent('<a href="example.com">Custom Link</a>
```

But when you try to insert a custom tag like, it does nothing when you click the custom button:

```
editor.selection.setContent('<custom-link href="example.com">Custom Link</custom-link>
```

I think the issue is that tinymce is cleaning up my custom tag ([docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/api/class_tinymce.Editor.html/#setcontent)).

I can also see in the docs above that you can pass setContent an args object, but I can't see what args you can actually pass.

Basically - how can I get tinymce to allow me to insert custom html tags? I think it might be with an argument passed in, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell TinyMCE what custom elements you wish to allow via its configuration.  You can do this with the `custom_elements` and `extended_valid_elements` configuration options.  For example:

```
custom_elements : 'custom-link',
extended_valid_elements : 'custom-link[href]'
```

Here is a working example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/wphaab  You can click Tools/Source Code to see the HTML that exists in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for that. This also worked without 'custom_elements', is it optional?